# How can I set the width of a pgfplot to fit that of a tikz matrix?

Tags: pgfplots, matrices

I'd like to be able to control the width of a `pgfplots` plot to that of a `matrix`. The plot should be below the `matrix`. Ideally the plot's dimension will depend only on the size of the `matrix` (so if the `matrix` changes so will the plot).

The plot and `matrix` are all part of a bigger `tikzpicture` that includes other components all positioned relative to each other, so I don't want to have two separate tikzpictures. Here's a minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[minimum size=4cm] (A) {
        \node{1};          & \node{2};                      \\
        \draw circle (.1); & \fill (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1); \\
    };
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[red,domain=0:10,samples=25] {x^2};
    \end{axis}        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've also added a picture of what I'd like it to look like (more or less). Note: I could only achieve that by using two separate tikzpictures...

[image: goal]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own measurement style via

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\tikzset{getwedist/.code args={#1 and #2}{% measures horizontal distance [#1.west-#2.east] 
  \pgfextra{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}%
  \xdef\mylength{\the\csname pgf@x\endcsname}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[minimum size=4cm,append after command={[getwedist=A and A]}] (A) {
        \node{1};          & \node{2};                      \\
        \draw circle (.1); & \fill (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1); \\
    };
    \begin{axis}[width=\mylength,height=2cm,anchor=north,at=(A.south)]
        \addplot[red,domain=0:10,samples=25] {x^2};
    \end{axis}        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And please have a look at [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: @12.yakir Related to the `minimal` class: The MWE package has in fact served me well to replicate images of arbitrary dimensions. :-) If you're bent on using MWE-specific stuff to post questions here.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick to article then (or try that MWE package). Your answer worked!